# Fill ComboBox inside a DataGridView with two Different Tables in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, datatable, datagridviewcombobox

I am capable of filling ComboBox with one Datatable. But i am not able to fill the same combobox with another datatable during runtime. First dataTable and Second Datatable contains different Data with Same Columns.

```
            dtOne= abcd.RetrivData();
            cnsmNm.DataSource = dtOne;
            cnsmNm.DisplayMember = "One_Name";
            cnsmNm.ValueMember = "One_Id";
```

second datatable

```
            dtSecond= efgh.RetrivData();
            cnsmNm.DataSource = dtSecond;
            cnsmNm.DisplayMember = "One_Name";
            cnsmNm.ValueMember = "One_Id";
```

Comment: What is the type of `dtOne` and `dtSecond`. Can you use [Enumerable.Concat Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)

Comment: they are getting data from database...those are datatables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DataTable.Merge method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx). Like this:

```
dtOne.Merge(dtSecond);
cnsmNm.DataSource = dtOne;
```

Comment: yes @Jacob Seleznev. Thanks for your Idea. i get my solution using Merge